# TCP socket server to websockets server

Tags: sockets, websocket

I am curious that is there some library available which can be used to convert TCP plain socket server to websockets server.
I have sever side implementation in C++ and want to convert it to websockets sever.

Comment: 1. questions about library recommendations are off-topic, be aware. 2. The question could be misunderstood, so I wonder...: are you looking to incorporate a WebSocket formatter / parser into the C++ server code or are you looking for an independent program?

Comment: @Myst I think I should ask it in better way.
Well, I have a server application written in C++ using plain TCP sockets. I want it to implement using websocket. I want to know that is there some wrapper which can be used over my application to convert it to websocket. BTW, the wrapper can be in Python/C++ or any other language.